# Best way to change column data for all rows over multiple dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider dataframes `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`.

`df1` and `df2` have an `id` column, and `df3` has a `from_id` and `to_id` column.

I need to iterate over all rows of `df3`, and replace `from_id` and `to_id` with new unique randomly generated UUIDs, and then update those in `df1` and `df2` where `(id == from_id) | (id == to_id)` (before the change to UUID).

I originally wanted to iterate over all rows of `df3` and simply check both `df1` and `df2` if they contain the original `from_id` or `to_id` inside the `id` column before replacing both, but [I found that iterating over pandas rows is a bad idea and slow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

I'm not sure how I can apply the other mentioned methods in that post to this problem since I'm not applying a simple function or calculating anything, and I think the way I had intended to do it would be too slow for big dataframes.

My current method that I believe to be slow and inefficient:

```py
import pandas as pd
import uuid

def rand_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid1()

def update_ids(df_places: pd.DataFrame, df_transitions: pd.DataFrame, df_arcs: pd.DataFrame) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    for i in range(len(df_arcs)):
        new_uuid_from = __rand_uuid()
        new_uuid_to = __rand_uuid()
        new_uuid_arc = __rand_uuid()

        df_transitions.loc[df_transitions.id == df_arcs.iloc[i]['sourceId'], 'id'] = new_uuid_from
        df_transitions.loc[df_transitions.id == df_arcs.iloc[i]['destinationId'], 'id'] = new_uuid_to

        df_places.loc[df_places.id == df_arcs.iloc[i]['sourceId'], 'id'] = new_uuid_from
        df_places.loc[df_places.id == df_arcs.iloc[i]['destinationId'], 'id'] = new_uuid_to

        df_arcs.iloc[i]['sourceId'] = new_uuid_from
        df_arcs.iloc[i]['destinationId'] = new_uuid_to
        df_arcs.iloc[i]['id'] = new_uuid_arc

    return df_places, df_transitions, df_arcs
```

Here `df_places` and `df_transitions` are above mentioned `df1` and `df2`, and `df_arcs` is `df3`

Example `df_places`

```
+---+----+
|   | id |
+---+----+
| 1 | a1 |
+---+----+
| 2 | c1 |
+---+----+
```

Example `df_transitions`:

```
+---+----+
|   | id |
+---+----+
| 1 | b1 |
+---+----+
```

Example `df_arcs`:

```
+---+----------+---------------+
|   | sourceId | destinationId |
+---+----------+---------------+
| 1 | a1       | b1            |
+---+----------+---------------+
| 2 | b1       | c1            |
+---+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: You can create a mapping dict of old: new and then use the map method.

Comment: Please show how `rand_uuid()` derive (i.e., all `import` and/or `def` lines). If you can generate a numpy array or pandas Series of UUIDs instead of one by one you can vectorize your operation and assign to other dfs using `merge`.

Comment: I added the method and imports, as well as example data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach:

```py
import itertools
import uuid

def rand_uuid():
    return uuid.uuid4()

rep_dict = {i: rand_uuid() for i in itertools.chain(df1.id, df2.id)}

df3.replace(rep_dict, inplace=True)
df3.id = df3.id.map(lambda x: rand_uuid())

df1.replace(rep_dict, inplace=True)
df2.replace(rep_dict, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I checked the generated dictionary `rep_dict`, and it seems to have generated the same UUIDs for all the entries.. Is this cause it happened too fast and UUID uses seconds, or something?

Comment: Inspect the generated IDs, they should be very similar, but different in the end. BTW, I'd use `uuid4`(https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) rather than `uuid1` to generate random unique identifiers not dependent on the host ID, the sequence number, and the time. I've update the answer. Give it a try!

Comment: You're right!.. I did some tests and it seems your method is SO fast, that it actually finished in 5 nanoseconds.. and UUID1 cannot generate that fast. UUID4 worked perfectly though.

One note for you answer: I also need to update the df3.id with a random UUID (differing from the ones matching df1 and df2). I figured it out, just thought I'd mention it for a possible edit to help future onlookers

Comment: Glad to help :)